# Removing Wordpress caption shortcodes from content, but keep content using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace

After migrating thousands of posts to a Laravel environment away from Wordpress, I've managed to mitigate most disasters and I'm left with the small issue of caption shortcodes in posts. They look like this:

```html
[caption id="attachment_38469" align="alignnone" width="1042"]<a href="https://uq.wd3.example.com/R-05591-1"><img class="size-full wp-image-38469" src="https://example.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/U0036.jpg" alt="This is an example" width="1042" height="2500" /></a> This is where the caption would go[/caption]
```

So far I have managed to strip the caption tags (even multiple captions) with the following code:

```php
$caption = 'Beginning stuff [caption id="attachment_38469" align="alignnone" width="1042"]<a href="https://uq.wd3.example.com/R-05591-1"><img class="size-full wp-image-38469" src="https://example.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/U0036.jpg" alt="This is an example" width="1042" height="2500" /></a> This is where the caption would go[/caption] ending stuff [caption id="attachment_38469" align="alignnone" width="1042"]<a href="https://uq.wd3.example.com/R-05591-1"><img class="size-full wp-image-38469" src="https://example.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/U0036.jpg" alt="This is an example" width="1042" height="2500" /></a> Second caption[/caption] and a last spot';

$c2 = preg_replace('%(\[caption\b[^\]]*\](.*?)(\[\/caption]))%', '$2', $caption);

// Preview:
print_r($c2, true);
```

Ideally I would love to turn these captions into:

```html
Content before<div class="captioned-image m-auto"><a href="*"><img src="*" /></a><span class="caption">*</span></div>content after
```

Where the `m-auto` tag is present if the align tag is "aligncenter", but that's really a bonus, if I can just get a span around the captions and a div around the captioned data that'd be great.

Comment: Another possible regex pattern that could allow for separation of caption from other data inside of caption tags... `\[caption\b[^\]]*\](.*?)((([^\.\?\!]*)[\.\?\!]?))(\[\/caption])`

Comment: Its a weird way of approaching the problem, but could you implement a short code over-ride with a custom plugin in PHP and then just pull the HTML of the post via an RSS feed or similair? So still use wordpress to do this "heavy lifting" and then just dump the rendered html of the post into laravel? I couch this as a thought... not a solution. ;)

Comment: @EvolveDigital or pull out the necessary PHP functions in Wordpress to have a similar rendering result for captions at least... I will look into that a bit

Comment: Referenced here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/img_caption_shortcode/ -> not really possible to extract as it's heavily embedded in Wordpress, so only routing the content through a Wordpress installation to get a "sanitised" content result would work for this end as you suggested...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up sticking with my original code.

```php
$sanitised_content = preg_replace('%(\[caption\b[^\]]*\](.*?)(\[\/caption]))%', '$2', $content);
```